# choice vs booleanparam (Both not working)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am creating a jenkins/groovy setup for creating a dashboard (Build with Parameters - in Jenkins) for users to input the values.
So fat I am good with the setups. The script I am using is:

```
parameters([
    choice(name: "Environment", 
           choices: ['Dev', 'QA', 'PRD'], 
           description: 'Select Env', required: true),

    choice(name: 'Select Type', 
           choices: ['EC2', 'EKS', 'ECS'], 
           description: 'Select type'),

    choice(name: 'permission', 
          choices: ['user', 'service account', 'policy'], 
          description: 'Select permission'),

    string(name: "TeamDL", 
           description: 'Provide Team Name', required: true),

    string(name: "ProductType", 
           description: 'Enter the product name', required: true),
           
    string(name: 'TeamWork', 
           description: 'Provide team DL', required: true),
])
```

In the above script, I am trying to provide 'Select Type' with multi-select options, like for example users should be able to select EC2 & EKS & ECS (all three) or only two options from the list.
SO I tried to replace 'choice' with 'booleanparam' (found this from researching online) and replacing it with  booleanparam made the options to disappear completely.

Not sure how I can achieve this option here folks..

Any tips how I can conclude my dashboard here, appreciate the help.

Cheers!

Multi-Select options from the Jenkins Dashboard (Build with Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You mix use declarative and scripted pipeline syntax to define parameters.

`choice()` only support single selection

```
parameters([
  # It's scripted style to define parameters
])

parameters {
  # it's declarative style to define parameters
}
```

If your Jenkins supports `extendedChoice` parameter type and your Jenksinfile use declarative style, your case can be done as following:

```
parameters {
    choice(name: "Environment", 
           choices: ['Dev', 'QA', 'PRD'], 
           description: 'Select Env', required: true)

    extendedChoice(name: 'Type', type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'EC2,EKS,ECS', 
                   multiSelectDelimiter: ',', quoteValue: true, 
                   description: 'Select type')

    choice(name: 'permission', 
          choices: ['user', 'service account', 'policy'] 
          description: 'Select permission'),

    string(name: "TeamDL", 
           description: 'Provide Team Name', required: true)

    string(name: "ProductType", 
           description: 'Enter the product name', required: true)

    string(name: 'TeamWork', 
           description: 'Provide team DL', required: true)
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply here, Yong. After setting up my groovy syntax, I am getting this weird error:



java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty.parameterDefinitions expects java.util.List<hudson.model.ParameterDefinition> but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2

Comment: Can you show your entire Jenksinfile?